# How to sort by the number of occurances and if occurances are same sort alphabatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have successfully sorted by the count of the words.

```
    def countem(s, n):
        hasht = {word: 0 for word in s.split()}
        for word in s.split():
            hasht[word] += 1
        srted = sorted(list(hasht.keys()),
                   key=lambda word: hasht[word], reverse=True)
        return srted


    print(countem("Hackers love bits, so does Alex Alex has just started his 
    career as hacker and found a special binary", 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, replace `hasht` with `collections.Counter` and then you can simply feed 2 critera to `sorted`:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

def countem(s):
    return sorted(Counter(s.split()).items(),
                  key= lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

pprint(countem("Hackers love bits, so does Alex Alex has just started his career as hacker and found a special binary"))
```

Output:

```
[('Alex', 2),
 ('Hackers', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('and', 1),
 ('as', 1),
 ('binary', 1),
 ('bits,', 1),
 ('career', 1),
 ('does', 1),
 ('found', 1),
 ('hacker', 1),
 ('has', 1),
 ('his', 1),
 ('just', 1),
 ('love', 1),
 ('so', 1),
 ('special', 1),
 ('started', 1)]
```

Note I implemented this in a case sensitive way (hence `'Hackers'` appears before `'a'`) but this could be changed.